# Why I am getting error : A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: AccountId?

Tags: apex, soql, compile-error

I want to set the Description field on Contact object same as the Industry field on the Account object. But when I am executing the below code I am getting error A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: AccountId. Can someone please explain why I am getting this error and how to go to the Industry field on the Account object from Contact object.

```
for(Contact c : [Select Id,AccountID,Description from Contact])
     {
         c.description = c.AccountID.Industry;
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the parent relationship name when you pull fields from upstream in a field path. For `AccountId`, the proper relationship name is `Account`.

**Incorrect**

```
AccountId.Industry
```

**Correct**

```
Account.Industry
```

Please note this field path must also be included in the query itself.